# Spring Boot 1.3.3 @EnableResourceServer and @EnableOAuth2Sso at the same time

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I want my server be a ResourceServer, which can accept a Bearer Access token

However, If such token doesn't exist, I want to use the OAuth2Server to authenticate my user.

I try to do like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableResourceServer
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

However, in this case, only the `@EnableResourceServer` annotation works. It returns

```
Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

And do not redirect me to the login page

I mentioned that the `@Order` is important, if I add the `@Order(0)` annotation,
I will be redirect to the login page, however, I cannot access my resource with the access_token in Http header:

```
Authorization : Bearer 142042b2-342f-4f19-8f53-bea0bae061fc
```

How can I achieve my goal? I want it use Access token and SSO at the same time.

Thanks~

Answer (score 14):

Using both configuration on same request would be ambiguous. There could be some solution for that, but more clear to define separate request groups:

- **OAuth2Sso**: for users coming from a browser, we want to redirect them to the authentication provider for the token
- **ResourceServer**: usually for api requests, coming with a token they got from somewhere (most probably from same authentication provider)

For achieving this, separate the configurations with request matcher:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean("resourceServerRequestMatcher")
    public RequestMatcher resources() {
        return new AntPathRequestMatcher("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .requestMatcher(resources()).authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

And exclude these from the sso filter chain:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SsoSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("resourceServerRequestMatcher")
    private RequestMatcher resources;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        RequestMatcher nonResoures = new NegatedRequestMatcher(resources);
        http
            .requestMatcher(nonResoures).authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

And put all your resources under `/resources/**`

Of course in this case both will use the same oauth2 configuration (`accessTokenUri`, `jwt.key-value`, etc.)

**UPDATE1:**

Actually you can achieve your original goal by using this request matcher for the above configuration:

```
new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Authorization")
```

**UPDATE2:**
(Explanation of @sid-morad's comment)

Spring Security creates a filter chain for each configuration. The request matcher for each filter chain is evaluated in the order of the configurations.
`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` has default order 100, and `ResourceServerConfiguration` is ordered 3 by default. Which means `ResourceServerConfiguration`'s request matcher evaluated first. This order can be overridden for these configurations like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration configuration;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setSecurityConfigurerOrder() {
        configuration.setOrder(3);
    }
...
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Order(100)
public class SsoSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
```

So yes, request matcher is not needed for `SsoSecurityConfiguration` in the above sample. But good to know the reasons behind :)

Comment: Your answer was helpful for me, Thanks! and want to point out `new NegatedRequestMatcher(resources)` part was not necessary in my case.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I addressed your comment in UPDATE2 section of my original post.

Comment: If the answer was helpful please accept the answer, it helps others

Comment: I've similar problem on zuul gateway. Using update#1 from solution solved it.