# Jhipster OAuth 2.0 / OIDC Authentication Authorization header with bearer token

Tags: oauth-2.0, jhipster, spring-security-oauth2, okta

I’ve used Jhipster to generate an app with the security option OAuth 2.0 / OIDC Authentication. I reconfigured said app to use Okta instead of keycloak following the instructions at http://www.jhipster.tech/security/#okta. All works as expected and the login flow performs as expected.

I now want to use OAuth 2.0 access_tokens to access my api resources from additional clients (Postman, Wordpress). I’ve retrieved a valid token from Okta added it to my Postman get request for localhost:8080/api/events and get a 401 in response.

[image: Postman get request]

The logs (https://pastebin.com/raw/R3D0GHHX) show that the spring security oauth2 doesn’t seem to be triggered by the presence of the Authorization bearer token.

1. Does Jhipster with OAuth 2.0 / OIDC Authentication support
   access_token in the Authorization bearer header or url param out of
   the box?
2. If not can you suggest what additional configurations I should make?

> **OAuth2Configuration.java**

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class OAuth2Configuration {
    public static final String SAVED_LOGIN_ORIGIN_URI = OAuth2Configuration.class.getName() + "_SAVED_ORIGIN";

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OAuth2Configuration.class);

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean saveLoginOriginFilter() {
        Filter filter = new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                            FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
                if (request.getRemoteUser() == null && request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/login")) {
                    String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
                    if (!StringUtils.isBlank(referrer) &&
                        request.getSession().getAttribute(SAVED_LOGIN_ORIGIN_URI) == null) {
                        log.debug("Saving login origin URI: {}", referrer);
                        request.getSession().setAttribute(SAVED_LOGIN_ORIGIN_URI, referrer);
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public static DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor defaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor() {
        return new DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor();
    }

    public static class DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, PriorityOrdered {

        @Override
        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (bean instanceof FilterChainProxy) {

                FilterChainProxy chains = (FilterChainProxy) bean;

                for (SecurityFilterChain chain : chains.getFilterChains()) {
                    for (Filter filter : chain.getFilters()) {
                        if (filter instanceof OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter) {
                            OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter =
                                (OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter) filter;
                            oAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter
                                .setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return bean;
        }

        @Override
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            return bean;
        }

        @Override
        public int getOrder() {
            return PriorityOrdered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
        }
    }
}
```

> **SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;

    private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;

    public SecurityConfiguration(CorsFilter corsFilter, SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport) {
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
    }

    @Bean
    public AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler() {
        return new AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
            .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
            .antMatchers("/content/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
            .antMatchers("/test/**")
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
            .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/profile-info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/websocket/tracker").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/websocket/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/configuration/ui").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN);

    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
        return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
    }
}
```

> **application.yml**

```
security:
    basic:
        enabled: false
    oauth2:
        client:
            access-token-uri: https://dev-800787.oktapreview.com/oauth2/ausb3ecnmsz8Ucjqw0h7/v1/token
            user-authorization-uri: https://dev-800787.oktapreview.com/oauth2/ausb3ecnmsz8Ucjqw0h7/v1/authorize
            client-id: <okta-client-id>
            client-secret: <okta-client-secret>
            client-authentication-scheme: form
            scope: openid profile email
        resource:
            filter-order: 3
            user-info-uri: https://dev-800787.oktapreview.com/oauth2/ausb3ecnmsz8Ucjqw0h7/v1/userinfo
            token-info-uri: https://dev-800787.oktapreview.com/oauth2/ausb3ecnmsz8Ucjqw0h7/v1/introspect
            prefer-token-info: false

server:
    session:
        cookie:
            http-only: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Spring Security OAuth's `@EnableResourceServer` for this functionality. If you're using Okta, you can also try using its [Spring Boot Starter](https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot).

Comment: Do you have any experience running these configurations together? Are there any known conflicts I should be aware of when using the generated code that makes use of @EnableOAuth2Sso alongside @EnableResourceServer? Should I be looking to change the current login flow implementation on my generated front end to make use of OAuth 2 access_tokens? Any resources or examples of best practices you would recommend? Appreciate your okta blog posts got me jump started on integrating all things spring with the okta platform.

Comment: No, I have not tried using them together. Please try it and let me know if you have any issues making things work. If you have problems, please post a new questions on Stack Overflow and tag it with "jhipster" again. That way, the whole team will receive a notification.

Answer (score 3):

Matt's answer point me to the right direction, thanks!

and here is my current working configuration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestHeaderRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class OAuth2AuthenticationConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public RequestMatcher resources() {
        return new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Authorization");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .requestMatcher(resources())
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44127684/2179502) was helpful too, thanks.